# How to restrict record from Team to Team in MS CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a question & I think it's very common question, I gone through many blogs & white paper but didn't get any straight answer.

Say I have the below Org structure:

- Org 1 - BU 1 - Sales VP - Sales Manager Team A - Sales Person Team A.
- Org 1 - BU 1 - Sales VP - Sales Manager Team B - Sales Person Team B.

I don't want that Team A can see any accounts or any records being created by Team B & vice-versa but Sales VP can see all the records.

- Approach A: Create a plugin/workflow & share the record accordingly.
- Approach B: Create a new BU which I don't want.

Please, let me know if is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use sharing like this, it can have performance issues,

Answer (score 3):

Approach B is correct

```
               ROOT BU - Sales VP
CHILD BU A - Team A          CHILD BU B - Team B
```

This is exactly the situation BUs are *meant* for